# JMeter using a variable as input for a response assertion pattern

Tags: jmeter

I have a test plan in JMeter that has a **Response Assertion** where I'd like to use a *variable* that comes from a **CSV Data Set Config**. So my Pattern looks like:

```
${assert1}
```

Which corresponds (at least in my thoughts) to what comes from the file used in **CSV Data Set Config**, but it doesn't work. I have seen multiple suggestions to use a **Regular Expression Extractor**,  but the examples I saw refer to something they're trying to capture from a page. In my case I am using an external csv file.

My question: how can I use a variable as input for a **Response Assertion** pattern ?

Comment: Can you show screenshots of your CSV config, and Response Assertion content ?

Comment: Thanks for letting me look into my config! I had used semi colon instead of comma-delimited. Stupid thing is, that I already had seen that I told myself don't forget that! But ok, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used a CSV Data Set Config as a source of string that I use in a url parameter, and then use a Response Assertion to seek out that parameter in the response.

- Variable name: `P`.
- URL: `/product/${P}`.
- The response assertion Parterns to Test: `${P}`.

I wonder if it is not necessary to use the CSV data variable in the request in order for it to be available in the response assertion?

Comment: No need to use it in request in order for it to be available in response

Comment: Thanks for the info PMD UBIK-INGENIERIE

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is right,
here your problem:
You want to use the value from your CSV as part of URL and that too via variable.

Solution:

Configure your CSV Data Set Config like this:

- Filename: url csv path
- variable name : assert1
- Delimiter : , (if your CSV comma separated)
- leave remaining unchanged

That's it you can use the variable assert1 anywhere: `${assert1}`.

Comment: Hi @iambritto there was a problem with my CSV config. I didn't configure it correctly. I didn't used the obligatory comma as a delimiter for my variable names. Thanks.